# Python Syntax error

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm getting the following error:

```
File "Question2.py", line 18
  except getopt.GetoptError as e:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Section of code that it comes from:

```
 try:
     opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "c:t:", ["class=","term="]
 except getopt.GetoptError as e:
     print 'Question2.py -c <class> -t <term>'
     system.exit(2)
 for opt, arg in opts:
     if opt in ('c', 'class'):
             selectclass = arg
     if opt in ('t', 'term'):
              selectterm = arg
```

What I am trying to do is get command line arguments working.  I want to be able to accept `-c` or `-class` and `-t` or `-term`.  I am following a tutorial located [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm).  I am unsure what is going wrong.

Comment: Missing `)` on previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a closing parenthesis at the end of this line:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "c:t:", ["class=","term="])
#                                                    here--^
```

Comment: @SethMMorton when I said that I had an 11m timer left on being able to.  I hadn't gotten back on SO until just now.